# Python3 Windows 7 file path handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have fetched files from windows shared drive having path as follows:

```
\\piyush123\piyushtech$\Piyush\ProFileTesting\May\Input_File\OMF\futurefilesomf.egus.xls
```

I want to fetch filename from this path which is `futurefilesomf.egus.xls`

when I tried as `file_path.split('\')` . It's giving error as `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

I can't do `file_path.split('\\')` because then it will give me `None`.

Even if I do `file_path.replace('\\','\')`, still same error.

What could be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marked as 3.x so I'll assume you have 3.4+ available for Pathlib

```
import pathlib

path = r"\\piyush123\piyushtech$\Piyush\ProFileTesting\May\Input_File\OMF\futurefilesomf.egus.xls"
print(pathlib.Path(path).name)
print(pathlib.Path(path).name == "futurefilesomf.egus.xls")
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do `file_path.split('\\')`. Do it like this:

```
>>> file_path=r"\\piyush123\piyushtech$\Piyush\ProFileTesting\May\Input_File\OMF\futurefilesomf.egus.xls"
>>> file_path.split('\\')
['', '', 'piyush123', 'piyushtech$', 'Piyush', 'ProFileTesting', 'May', 'Input_File', 'OMF', 'futurefilesomf.egus.xls']
```

Though you problably really need to combine it with a function from the `os.path` family, for example:

```
>>> os.path.splitunc(file_path)
('\\\\piyush123\\piyushtech$', '\\Piyush\\ProFileTesting\\May\\Input_File\\OMF\\futurefilesomf.egus.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `basename` instead of splitting:

```
>>> s = r"\\piyush123\piyushtech$\Piyush\ProFileTesting\May\Input_File\OMF\futurefilesomf.egus.xls"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.basename(s)
'futurefilesomf.egus.xls'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ntpath:

```
full_path = r'\\piyush123\piyushtech$\Piyush\ProFileTesting\May\Input_File\OMF\futurefilesomf.egus.xls'

import ntpath

ntpath.split(full_path)
```

which gives:

```
('\\\\piyush123\\piyushtech$\\Piyush\\ProFileTesting\\May\\Input_File\\OMF', 'futurefilesomf.egus.xls')
```